# Javascript interchange with command button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup an interchange using two texts boxes with a command button in between.

The idea is you type a reference/code in the left hand text box, click the button and it generates an alternative reference/code in the right hand text box.

The point being the user can check alternate bearing references if they can't find what they are looking for with the one they have.

The code I use so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
oldRef = new Array ("Z582","T608","A173");
newRef = new Array ("C850","S708","X449");
function convert()
{
    document.getElementById("v2").value = "";
    for (index=0 ; index < oldRef.length ; index++)
    {
        if ( document.getElementById("v1").value == oldRef[index] )                      
document.getElementById("v2").value = newRef[index];
    }
}
</script>
```

---

V1 and V2 refer the the text box ID.

This works with the text boxes but I don't know how to incorporate the command button into this so that they need to click the button in the middle for it to generate.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best

Will

Comment: Why have the button at all? Why not start 'searching' and show results while the user is typing? Use the `onkeypress` event.

Comment: Yeah but then checking on losing focus or on blur is far better

Answer (score 0):

So essentially there are two things that you need to accomplish what you asked. You need to create a element within your HTML, in this case a button. You then need to catch the event that you want to catch from that element and then execute you `convert` function.

This is one example of accomplishing this:

So create an button within your HTML

```
 <button id="btn_command">Command</button>
```

Then in Javascript you want to target that button and add an event listener to that button. In the example the below the variable `var btnCommand` is set to the html button by using the `getElementById` method to get that button with that id. Then we add and event listener to that element that when clicked it executes your convert function.

```
var btnCommand = document.getElementById ("btn_command") ;

btnCommand.addEventListener("click", convert, false) ;
```

If you want to use jQuery you would do something like this.

```
$('#btn_command').on('click', function() { convert(); });
```

Here is another quick and dirty way to just test you button with your function. ***It is not a best idea to mix your javascript inline with your html*** but just to test your button and if your convert function is doing that you think you could just say

```
<button onClick="convert()">Command</button>
```

Well there are few ways to accomplish what you asked. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty Easy stuff what you need to do is to use onclick of the button like this

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("v2").value = "";
    for (var index=0 ; index < oldRef.length ; index++) {
        if (document.getElementById("v1").value == oldRef[index])     
            document.getElementById("v2").value = newRef[index];
    }
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/9ksg6/)

I hope this is waht you want....